# How do you implement automatic generated different numbers of tabs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

my problem is that depending on how many array items I need different amount of tabs. So if my array is like dog, cat, mouse - i need 3 tabs named with dog cat mouse. If i have only dog and cat so only have 2 tabs named dog and cat. I hope you all know what I mean. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tabs need Ionic Page to work: `<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>`. So, does every item in that array have an associated page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over your array of tabs:

`<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [root]="tab.page" [tabTitle]="tab.title"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>`

`tabs = [{
    page: HomePage,
    title: 'Home'
  }, {
    page: AboutPage,
    title: 'About'
  }];`

[See stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hrlro5)